# Update dictionary with nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have this json file used to list `material` by `ref` -> `color` and `size`:

```
{
    "base": {
        "ref": {
            "3021000": {
                "color": {
                    "bleu azur": {
                        "size": {
                            "01": "3021000-80300-01",
                            "13": "3021000-80300-13",
                            "12": "3021000-80300-12",
                            "36": "3021000-80300-36"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "customer_ref": {}
    }
}
```

With a program I will load the `json` as a `dict` and search the `dict` to try and find the full ref corresponding to the value of a size (the full ref for the material `3021000 bleu azur 01` is `3021000-80300-01`

It's working like a charm, but now, if I have a `material` with: `ref=3021000`, `color=blanc` and `size=01`, it doesn't exist in the dict, so I would like to insert the missing `key - value`: `{"blanc": {"size": {"01": "corresponding full ref"}}}`

I tried this:

```
ref = "3021000"
color = "blanc"
size = "01"
full_ref = "corresponding full ref"
missing_data = {ref: {"color": {color: {"size": {size: full_ref}}}}}
data["base"]["ref"] = missing_data
```

but it overwrite the dictionary; what I would like is to update the dict, not overwrite it.

Comment: In 2021, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: This isn't the subject of the post, I wouldn't be using the good old python 2 if I could.

Comment: We can't know that if you don't tell us that. My recommendation would be to include a short rationale for why you can't use Python 3 when posting Python 2 questions these days, going forward (no need on this question as long as these comments remain here). We still get a steady trickle of questions from people who honestly don't know that Python 2 is dead.

Comment: It is irrelevant to the question, the tag "python-2.7" was present, I was expecting an answer corresponding to my python version, changing python version isn't a valid solution. I agree it is "outdated", but I'm using Sikuli wich use jython 2.7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import json

d = {
    "base": {
        "ref": {
            "3021000": {
                "color": {
                    "bleu azur": {
                        "size": {
                            "01": "3021000-80300-01",
                            "13": "3021000-80300-13",
                            "12": "3021000-80300-12",
                            "36": "3021000-80300-36"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "customer_ref": {}
    }
}

ref = "3021000"
color = "blanc"
size = "01"
full_ref = "corresponding full ref"
missing_data = {color: {"size": {size: full_ref}}}
d["base"]["ref"][ref]["color"].update(missing_data)
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "base": {
    "ref": {
      "3021000": {
        "color": {
          "bleu azur": {
            "size": {
              "01": "3021000-80300-01",
              "13": "3021000-80300-13",
              "12": "3021000-80300-12",
              "36": "3021000-80300-36"
            }
          },
          "blanc": {
            "size": {
              "01": "corresponding full ref"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "customer_ref": {}
  }
}
```